# Best way to get all items that match quickly

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

Below is the snippet of code in question. We are trying to match an item with a collection of item properties. The code below works, and we return what we need, however it's quite slow. We are curious what the best way to go about doing this is. Any help is greatly appreciated. We are open to options in SQL as well. Thank you!

```
var items = await GetItemsAsync(repository, a, b);
// Next we need to get all of the properties for those items. 
var results = new List<Result>();
foreach(var c in items)
{
   c.Properties = await GetItemProperties(repository, c.Id);
   var matchedProperties = selectedProperties.Where(si => c.Properties.Any(i => i.Id == si.Id));
   if(matchedProperties.Count() > 0)
   {
       results.Add(new Result(c)
       {
           MatchedProperties = matchedProperties,
           Relevance = (decimal)matchedProperties.Count() / (decimal)selectedProperties.Count()
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: what part of your code is exaclty slow?GetItemsAsync or GetItemProperties or where in selectedProperties.since we don't know what code is inside  those methods.it's hard to help.the only thing I can say is just int selectedProperties.Count() cast decimal once.

Comment: Think towards bitmasks, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main reason for bad performance is that you are going through the result of items and execute new sql query in every single item. So you can not be sure how many sql query hits will be there. The amount of queries is 1 + result of items.

What about if you change it to this:

```
var items = await GetItemsAsync(repository, a, b);

var ids = items.Select(c => c.id);

var properties = await GetItemsProperties(repository, ids);

 // map items and properties after this without sql queries
```

If you do it in that way you will have only two (2) sql queries.

The sql could be like:

```
SELECT * FROM properties_table WHERE itemId IN (/*your ids here: 1, 2, 3 etc*/)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can even get down to one SQL Access if you write a new method which gets all desired items together with their properties instead of first getting their id and then get the properties bases on the id(s). I completely agree with Mr. Kuosa that the numerous database accesses (depending on the number of items) can slow down performance significantly.